# Fetch data and setState every time just before component renders in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, render, lifecycle

There is the case , i have a modal which shows some data from its state ( an array ) , and it's state is getting set in componentDidMount() function like docs suggests. I need to show updated data every time when modal opened up.So i was able to do that with componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) function , like i showed below .
But what if i want to migrate to getDerivedStateFromProps function ? How am i going to achieve same behaviour with it ?

### Here is the component code simplified for sake :

```
export class PastOrdersModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      past: {},
      isLoading: false,
      modalVisible: false
    };
  }

  async componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {  
    const response = await this.fetchPast();
    this.setState({ past: response });
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await this.fetchPast();
    this.setState({ past: response });
  }
   ...
   ... some callback functions for handling modalvisible value ....
   ...
   render(){
   // here rendering state array with this.state.past.map(......) etc.
  }
```

The fetchPast function makes a GET request to server of mine , all you need to know that it returns an array to me. This is working perfectly. ComponentWillReceiveProps gets called every time because parent component sends modalVisible props everytime.
But componentWillRecieveProps is deprecating and i could not make the same behavior with getDerivedStateFromProps.How should i implement same thing with it.
**Note**: ı am not going to use redux ,i am not going to use mobx , i know how to use them and it's not what i want. The thing is  the behavior i want is soo simple i don't want to pass values another component , i don't want to pass values another screen , i just want to update a simple component that is all but either the framework is pushing it's limits to make simplest tasks hardests thing ever or i am missing really huge point.(probably latter one :) ) 
**Note**: I know i am not doing anything with nextProps , that was the only solution i found.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your Component as a function so you can use [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

```
const PastOrdersModal = (props) => {
  const [past, setPast] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisibility] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPast = async () => {
      const response = await fetchPast();
      setPast(response);
    };
    if(modalVisible) fetchPast();
  }, [modalVisible])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPast = async () => {
      const response = await fetchPast();
      setPast(response);
    };
    fetchPast();
  }, [])

   ...
   ... some callback functions for handling modalvisible value ....
   ...
   return <YourComponent />
```

The variables we created inside `[]` at the top are the ones we are using for the state. The first one will be the state as itself and the second one is a function responsible for updating that state. The `useEffect` hook will simulate the life cycle methods for Class Components, it receives a callback that will be executed and a second argument. The second argument is the one that will indicate when it is going to be triggered. For instance, you can see 2 `useEffect`s, the one with the empty array will tell the hook to execute just once, similar as `componentDidMount`. The other one will be triggered when `modalVisible` changes, so everytime you change its value it will be executed, that's why we only validate if the modal is visible (is `true`) we do the fetch, otherwise the fetch won't be executed

Comment: I am new to react hooks , never used them.I will try your answer asap and vote solution , but if you dont mind , i am curious if there is another workaround to achieve same thing without hooks ?